# Library installation on BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am fairly new to programming under the Linux and it seems especially a bit different on BeagleBone, where there is no (I dont have any) display output (I do everything in Putty). Right now I got to point, where I would like to use some extra libraries, LibEvent that is.

I know it is stored on GitHub and I also know, that there is a way how to download it right onto BBB (I have a Wifi dongle on my BBB already configured).

I would really appriciate some tutorial/booklet on "How to install libs on BBB" in general, but any form of help would be great. I havent found any comprehensive tutorial so far.

My BBB:
Angstrom distribution
, Putty SSH-ing to USB
, Wifi connection
, managing files by WinSCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I found the answer in these simple 3 commands:

1) opkg update
2) opkg install qt4-embedded --force-depends
3) opkg install libevent